# VueJS change content of component slots globally

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to use component for selectbox. But I need change texts in slots (eg. Whoops! Nothing here.).

I know how to change component slots in template"

```
<v-select>
    <span slot="no-options">
      My text which will displayed
    </span>
</v-select>
```

But how to change content of slots globally? So whenever I use component, slots will have own defined content (not default which is in component).

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add more description to understand the question better? "slots will have translated content."

Comment: Added. I need change content of slots - translate messages to another language.

Comment: This you can achieve with the use of `i18n`. https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/component.html#translation-in-functional-component

Comment: ok, but firstly I must mirror existing component (create wrapper) and there use i18n. Because I need localize 3rd library component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand。I think you need to create a new component！

```
<template>
  <v-select>
    <span slot="no-options">
      My text which will displayed
    </span>
  </v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MySelect',
}
</script>
```

So you use it like this.

```
<template>
  <my-select></my-select>
</template>

<script>
import MySelect from './MySelect.vue'
export default {
  components: {name: 'MySelect'}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cloydlau/vue-global-config provides the ability to programmatically pass **global slots**, **global scoped slots**, global props, global attrs, global listeners and global hooks, support Vue 2.6/2.7/3.